# Adafruit Huzzah32 esp32 4mb flash SPIFFS size

Tags: arduino, adafruit, esp32, spiffs

I have an Adafruit Huzzah32 dev board based on the esp32 wifi chip. It is an Arduino based dev board. Here is a link:

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-huzzah32-esp32-feather

It has 4MB of onboard flash that is used for the sketch. The flash can also be partitioned as a flash file system using the spiffs libraries.

It appears that you don't have a choice about how big you can make that partition. I need more flash for my sketch and only a little bit for the flash file system.

I can't seem to figure out how to change the size of the file system partition.

Can someone help me figure this out?

Comment: edit boards.txt. copy the SPIFFS options from other 4 MB board section

Comment: Can you tell me where this boards.txt file is? I can't seem to find where the boards I have installed are located. I did find one boards.txt file, but all of them have the same max size for the upload and it is set to 1310720. I can't find any that are larger than that. Any more details you can give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should not change the size, but copy the lines for the SPIFFS menu options

Comment: Will that give me more space for the app? Where exactly should the boards.txt file be on macOS?

Comment: I found the right board and copied the settings and it works. Thank you so much for helping with this. If you wouldn't mind copying your answer to an actual answer I can mark it as the answer.